"Savoir pour" vs "savoir à propos de" ?
Je pensais qu'en général on utilise savoir à propos de qch pour exprimer to know about something, mais ce soir je suis tombé sur cette phrase dans un livre:

On ne voulait pas que vous sachiez pour le fantôme, dit-il doucement.

J'ai pas déjà rencontré savoir pour quelque chose. Quelle est la différence ? Quand doit-on utiliser cette formulation au lieu de l'autre ?
Est-ce qu'il y a des autres moyens de l'exprimer, en plus ?

En fonction de ce que vous voulez dire exactement, il y aussi « s'y connaître en [qch] » et « être au courant de [qch] ».

This question is similar to: « J'ai appris pour ton père ». If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Disagree, not a duplicate, just has overlap

Dans cette phrase, savoir pour le est tout à fait idiomatique. Savoir à propos de est bien sûr aussi possible avec sensiblement le même sens mais est un peu plus soutenu.
Savoir pour le/la/les sous-entend aussi souvent qu'il s'agit de quelque chose d'important, de secret, de compromettant, etc.
@None en commentaire :
Le sens de pour est le suivant dans le TLFi :

C.− Par extension En ce qui concerne (la pers. ou la chose désignée par le complément)

On peut aussi donner pour ce qui est de , en ce qui concerne, au sujet de, les trois étant d'un niveau de langue plus élevé.
@DerekAllums en commentaire :
On dit aussi être au courant de qque chose.
C'est probablement la formule la plus employée :

On ne voulait pas que vous soyez au courant [pour le]/[à propos du] fantôme, dit-il doucement.

To know about something peut aussi se traduire par s'y connaître en quelque chose (commentaire de @DerekAllums aussi):

I know about cooking.
Je m'y connais en cuisine.

C'est autre chose que savoir pour [...].

On peut aussi donner  *pour ce qui est de * , en ce qui concerne, au sujet de les trois  étant d'un niveau de langue plus élevé (donc peut-être pas compatible avec un fantôme ?) . Pour dire que c'est admis TLF C.
